# Can a list be made available to column in subsite?

Tags: list, site-template, lookup-column

I am creating a project management site template.  This template will be used to create PM subsites in our corporate PM site.  In the subsite task list, I want to add a "Work Area" column that is a lookup to a list in the parent site, so that the work areas list needs only to be maintained in one place.

I have seen posts regarding adding WebParts to look at parent site lists, but nothing on how to add a parent site list as a lookup for a column.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: @Naomi Frost: Welcome to our site and thanks for your question! Some quick tips on how it works... press the up arrow next to an answer if it's helpful, and press the tick if it answers your question. If you'd like to leave a comment for someone, use the "add comment" link under their answer. Thanks and hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: @Naomi: Now that your account is fixed up you should be able to place a tick next to an answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its not entirely clear for me from your description if we are talking sub sites or sub site collections.

If its just sub sites, like team sites under SITES managed path, you can map a normal lookup site column to point to the list in the root site of the site collection and add that column to your task list.

If your are working on different site collections you need to look for third party tools like Steve mentions.

hth
Anders Rask

Answer (score 1):

If you define a Site Column and or Content Type at the parent site you can reuse that from the sub-sites.  [Here is a blog post](http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-site-columns-to-reuse-data.html) I wrote about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are third party companies where you can buy this functionality.

Or it's available free on codeplex: [SharePoint Filtered Lookup Field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)